# Kafka Consumer not subscribing to the messages | Spring boot

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have created a simple Kafka Producer and Consumer logic.
When I am publishing the message to Kafka Topic, the message is sent successfully but the consumer logic in my code is not automatically subscribing to those messages.

I tried to subscribe to those messages using kafka-console-consumer.bat then I can see the messages coming through (when published).

**`kafka-console-consumer.bat --topic ispTopic --from-beginning --bootstrap-server localhost:9092`**

`application.properties`

```
spring.kafka.consumer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.consumer.group-id=group1
spring.kafka.consumer.auto-offset-reset=earliest
spring.kafka.consumer.key-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
spring.kafka.consumer.value-deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

spring.kafka.producer.bootstrap-servers=localhost:9092
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
logging.level.org.apache.kafka=DEBUG
```

`Topic Configuration-`

```
package com.scb.kafka.config;

import org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.NewTopic;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.TopicBuilder;

@Configuration
public class KafkaTopicConfig {

  @Bean
  public NewTopic testTopic() {
    return TopicBuilder.name("ispTopic").build();
  }

}
```

`Producer-`

```
package com.scb.kafka.producer;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.scb.kafka.constants.AppConstants;

@Service
public class KafkaProducer {
  
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaProducer.class);
  
  @Autowired
  private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;
  
  public void sendMessage(String message){
    LOGGER.info(String.format("Message sent -> %s", message));
    kafkaTemplate.send("ispTopic", message);
}

}
```

`Consumer`

```
package com.scb.kafka.consumer;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.annotation.KafkaListener;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.scb.kafka.constants.AppConstants;

@Service
public class KafkaConsumer {
  
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(KafkaConsumer.class);

  @KafkaListener(topics = "ispTopic",
                  groupId = "group1")
  public void consume(String message){
      LOGGER.info(String.format("Message received -> %s", message));
      System.out.println("Message received by the consumer : " + message);
  }

}
```

The flow is not even going inside the consumer logic.

Please find my debug logs below -

```
2023-06-27T11:44:52.568+05:30  INFO 15744 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-06-27T11:44:52.568+05:30  INFO 15744 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-06-27T11:44:52.569+05:30  INFO 15744 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 0 ms
publish message : hello
2023-06-27T11:44:52.597+05:30  INFO 15744 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] com.scb.kafka.producer.KafkaProducer     : Message sent -> hello
2023-06-27T11:44:52.614+05:30  INFO 15744 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.k.clients.producer.ProducerConfig    : ProducerConfig values: 
    acks = -1
    auto.include.jmx.reporter = true
    batch.size = 16384
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    buffer.memory = 33554432
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = producer-1
    compression.type = none
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    delivery.timeout.ms = 120000
    enable.idempotence = true
    interceptor.classes = []
    key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
    linger.ms = 0
    max.block.ms = 60000
    max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
    max.request.size = 1048576
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metadata.max.idle.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partitioner.adaptive.partitioning.enable = true
    partitioner.availability.timeout.ms = 0
    partitioner.class = null
    partitioner.ignore.keys = false
    receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retries = 2147483647
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.connect.timeout.ms = null
    sasl.login.read.timeout.ms = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.login.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
    sasl.login.retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    sasl.oauthbearer.clock.skew.seconds = 30
    sasl.oauthbearer.expected.audience = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.expected.issuer = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.refresh.ms = 3600000
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.max.ms = 10000
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.oauthbearer.jwks.endpoint.url = null
    sasl.oauthbearer.scope.claim.name = scope
    sasl.oauthbearer.sub.claim.name = sub
    sasl.oauthbearer.token.endpoint.url = null
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.max.ms = 30000
    socket.connection.setup.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.certificate.chain = null
    ssl.keystore.key = null
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.3
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.certificates = null
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
    transactional.id = null
    value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

2023-06-27T11:44:52.631+05:30  INFO 15744 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Instantiated an idempotent producer.
2023-06-27T11:44:52.664+05:30 DEBUG 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.internals.Sender  : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Starting Kafka producer I/O thread.
2023-06-27T11:44:52.666+05:30 DEBUG 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Transition from state UNINITIALIZED to INITIALIZING
2023-06-27T11:44:52.666+05:30  INFO 15744 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 3.4.1
2023-06-27T11:44:52.667+05:30  INFO 15744 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 8a516edc2755df89
2023-06-27T11:44:52.667+05:30  INFO 15744 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1687846492664
2023-06-27T11:44:52.668+05:30 DEBUG 15744 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer     : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Kafka producer started
2023-06-27T11:44:52.820+05:30 DEBUG 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Enqueuing transactional request InitProducerIdRequestData(transactionalId=null, transactionTimeoutMs=2147483647, producerId=-1, producerEpoch=-1)
2023-06-27T11:44:52.821+05:30 DEBUG 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Initialize connection to node localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) for sending metadata request
2023-06-27T11:44:52.822+05:30 DEBUG 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils     : Resolved host localhost as 127.0.0.1
2023-06-27T11:44:52.822+05:30 DEBUG 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Initiating connection to node localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) using address localhost/127.0.0.1
2023-06-27T11:44:52.833+05:30 DEBUG 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] o.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Created socket with SO_RCVBUF = 32768, SO_SNDBUF = 131072, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node -1
2023-06-27T11:44:52.835+05:30 DEBUG 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Completed connection to node -1. Fetching API versions.
2023-06-27T11:44:52.835+05:30 DEBUG 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Initiating API versions fetch from node -1.
2023-06-27T11:44:52.838+05:30 DEBUG 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Sending API_VERSIONS request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=API_VERSIONS, apiVersion=3, clientId=producer-1, correlationId=0, headerVersion=2) and timeout 30000 to node -1: ApiVersionsRequestData(clientSoftwareName='apache-kafka-java', clientSoftwareVersion='3.4.1')
2023-06-27T11:44:52.882+05:30 DEBUG 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Received API_VERSIONS response from node -1 for request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=API_VERSIONS, apiVersion=3, clientId=producer-1, correlationId=0, headerVersion=2): ApiVersionsResponseData(errorCode=0, apiKeys=[ApiVersion(apiKey=0, minVersion=0, maxVersion=9), ApiVersion(apiKey=1, minVersion=0, maxVersion=12), ApiVersion(apiKey=2, minVersion=0, maxVersion=6), ApiVersion(apiKey=3, minVersion=0, maxVersion=11), ApiVersion(apiKey=4, minVersion=0, maxVersion=5), ApiVersion(apiKey=5, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=6, minVersion=0, maxVersion=7), ApiVersion(apiKey=7, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=8, minVersion=0, maxVersion=8), ApiVersion(apiKey=9, minVersion=0, maxVersion=7), ApiVersion(apiKey=10, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=11, minVersion=0, maxVersion=7), ApiVersion(apiKey=12, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=13, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=14, minVersion=0, maxVersion=5), ApiVersion(apiKey=15, minVersion=0, maxVersion=5), ApiVersion(apiKey=16, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=17, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=18, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=19, minVersion=0, maxVersion=7), ApiVersion(apiKey=20, minVersion=0, maxVersion=6), ApiVersion(apiKey=21, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=22, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=23, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=24, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=25, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=26, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=27, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=28, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=29, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=30, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=31, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=32, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=33, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=34, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=35, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=36, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=37, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=38, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=39, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=40, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=41, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=42, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=43, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=44, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=45, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=46, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=47, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=48, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=49, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=50, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=51, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=56, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=57, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=60, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=61, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0)], throttleTimeMs=0, supportedFeatures=[], finalizedFeaturesEpoch=0, finalizedFeatures=[], zkMigrationReady=false)
2023-06-27T11:44:52.919+05:30 DEBUG 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node -1 has finalized features epoch: 0, finalized features: [], supported features: [], API versions: (Produce(0): 0 to 9 [usable: 9], Fetch(1): 0 to 12 [usable: 12], ListOffsets(2): 0 to 6 [usable: 6], Metadata(3): 0 to 11 [usable: 11], LeaderAndIsr(4): 0 to 5 [usable: 5], StopReplica(5): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], UpdateMetadata(6): 0 to 7 [usable: 7], ControlledShutdown(7): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], OffsetCommit(8): 0 to 8 [usable: 8], OffsetFetch(9): 0 to 7 [usable: 7], FindCoordinator(10): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], JoinGroup(11): 0 to 7 [usable: 7], Heartbeat(12): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], LeaveGroup(13): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], SyncGroup(14): 0 to 5 [usable: 5], DescribeGroups(15): 0 to 5 [usable: 5], ListGroups(16): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], SaslHandshake(17): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], ApiVersions(18): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], CreateTopics(19): 0 to 7 [usable: 7], DeleteTopics(20): 0 to 6 [usable: 6], DeleteRecords(21): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], InitProducerId(22): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], OffsetForLeaderEpoch(23): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], AddPartitionsToTxn(24): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], AddOffsetsToTxn(25): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], EndTxn(26): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], WriteTxnMarkers(27): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], TxnOffsetCommit(28): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], DescribeAcls(29): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], CreateAcls(30): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], DeleteAcls(31): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], DescribeConfigs(32): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], AlterConfigs(33): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], AlterReplicaLogDirs(34): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], DescribeLogDirs(35): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], SaslAuthenticate(36): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], CreatePartitions(37): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], CreateDelegationToken(38): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], RenewDelegationToken(39): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], ExpireDelegationToken(40): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], DescribeDelegationToken(41): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], DeleteGroups(42): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], ElectLeaders(43): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], IncrementalAlterConfigs(44): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], AlterPartitionReassignments(45): 0 [usable: 0], ListPartitionReassignments(46): 0 [usable: 0], OffsetDelete(47): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeClientQuotas(48): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], AlterClientQuotas(49): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], DescribeUserScramCredentials(50): 0 [usable: 0], AlterUserScramCredentials(51): 0 [usable: 0], AlterPartition(56): 0 [usable: 0], UpdateFeatures(57): 0 [usable: 0], Envelope(58): UNSUPPORTED, DescribeCluster(60): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeProducers(61): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeTransactions(65): UNSUPPORTED, ListTransactions(66): UNSUPPORTED, AllocateProducerIds(67): UNSUPPORTED).
2023-06-27T11:44:52.921+05:30 DEBUG 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Sending metadata request MetadataRequestData(topics=[MetadataRequestTopic(topicId=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA, name='ispTopic')], allowAutoTopicCreation=true, includeClusterAuthorizedOperations=false, includeTopicAuthorizedOperations=false) to node localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null)
2023-06-27T11:44:52.922+05:30 DEBUG 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Sending METADATA request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=METADATA, apiVersion=11, clientId=producer-1, correlationId=1, headerVersion=2) and timeout 30000 to node -1: MetadataRequestData(topics=[MetadataRequestTopic(topicId=AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA, name='ispTopic')], allowAutoTopicCreation=true, includeClusterAuthorizedOperations=false, includeTopicAuthorizedOperations=false)
2023-06-27T11:44:52.923+05:30 DEBUG 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.internals.Sender  : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Sending transactional request InitProducerIdRequestData(transactionalId=null, transactionTimeoutMs=2147483647, producerId=-1, producerEpoch=-1) to node localhost:9092 (id: -1 rack: null) with correlation ID 2
2023-06-27T11:44:52.924+05:30 DEBUG 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Sending INIT_PRODUCER_ID request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=INIT_PRODUCER_ID, apiVersion=4, clientId=producer-1, correlationId=2, headerVersion=2) and timeout 30000 to node -1: InitProducerIdRequestData(transactionalId=null, transactionTimeoutMs=2147483647, producerId=-1, producerEpoch=-1)
2023-06-27T11:44:52.937+05:30 DEBUG 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Received METADATA response from node -1 for request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=METADATA, apiVersion=11, clientId=producer-1, correlationId=1, headerVersion=2): MetadataResponseData(throttleTimeMs=0, brokers=[MetadataResponseBroker(nodeId=0, host='INNFZ3C0X2.zone1.scb.net', port=9092, rack=null)], clusterId='zCD3prCQRJyumxRY1Cs8jg', controllerId=0, topics=[MetadataResponseTopic(errorCode=0, name='ispTopic', topicId=AGozXTQtQnimW_IhXMI_fA, isInternal=false, partitions=[MetadataResponsePartition(errorCode=0, partitionIndex=0, leaderId=0, leaderEpoch=0, replicaNodes=[0], isrNodes=[0], offlineReplicas=[])], topicAuthorizedOperations=-2147483648)], clusterAuthorizedOperations=-2147483648)
2023-06-27T11:44:52.940+05:30  INFO 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Resetting the last seen epoch of partition ispTopic-0 to 0 since the associated topicId changed from null to AGozXTQtQnimW_IhXMI_fA
2023-06-27T11:44:52.942+05:30  INFO 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Cluster ID: zCD3prCQRJyumxRY1Cs8jg
2023-06-27T11:44:52.942+05:30 DEBUG 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Updated cluster metadata updateVersion 2 to MetadataCache{clusterId='zCD3prCQRJyumxRY1Cs8jg', nodes={0=INNFZ3C0X2.zone1.scb.net:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)}, partitions=[PartitionMetadata(error=NONE, partition=ispTopic-0, leader=Optional[0], leaderEpoch=Optional[0], replicas=0, isr=0, offlineReplicas=)], controller=INNFZ3C0X2.zone1.scb.net:9092 (id: 0 rack: null)}
2023-06-27T11:44:52.953+05:30 DEBUG 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Received INIT_PRODUCER_ID response from node -1 for request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=INIT_PRODUCER_ID, apiVersion=4, clientId=producer-1, correlationId=2, headerVersion=2): InitProducerIdResponseData(throttleTimeMs=0, errorCode=0, producerId=2004, producerEpoch=0)
2023-06-27T11:44:52.953+05:30  INFO 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] ProducerId set to 2004 with epoch 0
2023-06-27T11:44:52.954+05:30 DEBUG 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Transition from state INITIALIZING to READY
2023-06-27T11:44:52.955+05:30 DEBUG 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.ClientUtils     : Resolved host INNFZ3C0X2.zone1.scb.net as 10.141.157.178,192.168.1.11
2023-06-27T11:44:52.955+05:30 DEBUG 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Initiating connection to node INNFZ3C0X2.zone1.scb.net:9092 (id: 0 rack: null) using address INNFZ3C0X2.zone1.scb.net/10.141.157.178
2023-06-27T11:44:52.960+05:30 DEBUG 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] o.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Created socket with SO_RCVBUF = 32768, SO_SNDBUF = 131072, SO_TIMEOUT = 0 to node 0
2023-06-27T11:44:52.960+05:30 DEBUG 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Completed connection to node 0. Fetching API versions.
2023-06-27T11:44:52.960+05:30 DEBUG 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Initiating API versions fetch from node 0.
2023-06-27T11:44:52.960+05:30 DEBUG 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Sending API_VERSIONS request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=API_VERSIONS, apiVersion=3, clientId=producer-1, correlationId=3, headerVersion=2) and timeout 30000 to node 0: ApiVersionsRequestData(clientSoftwareName='apache-kafka-java', clientSoftwareVersion='3.4.1')
2023-06-27T11:44:52.984+05:30 DEBUG 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Received API_VERSIONS response from node 0 for request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=API_VERSIONS, apiVersion=3, clientId=producer-1, correlationId=3, headerVersion=2): ApiVersionsResponseData(errorCode=0, apiKeys=[ApiVersion(apiKey=0, minVersion=0, maxVersion=9), ApiVersion(apiKey=1, minVersion=0, maxVersion=12), ApiVersion(apiKey=2, minVersion=0, maxVersion=6), ApiVersion(apiKey=3, minVersion=0, maxVersion=11), ApiVersion(apiKey=4, minVersion=0, maxVersion=5), ApiVersion(apiKey=5, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=6, minVersion=0, maxVersion=7), ApiVersion(apiKey=7, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=8, minVersion=0, maxVersion=8), ApiVersion(apiKey=9, minVersion=0, maxVersion=7), ApiVersion(apiKey=10, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=11, minVersion=0, maxVersion=7), ApiVersion(apiKey=12, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=13, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=14, minVersion=0, maxVersion=5), ApiVersion(apiKey=15, minVersion=0, maxVersion=5), ApiVersion(apiKey=16, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=17, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=18, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=19, minVersion=0, maxVersion=7), ApiVersion(apiKey=20, minVersion=0, maxVersion=6), ApiVersion(apiKey=21, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=22, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=23, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=24, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=25, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=26, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=27, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=28, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=29, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=30, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=31, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=32, minVersion=0, maxVersion=4), ApiVersion(apiKey=33, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=34, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=35, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=36, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=37, minVersion=0, maxVersion=3), ApiVersion(apiKey=38, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=39, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=40, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=41, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=42, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=43, minVersion=0, maxVersion=2), ApiVersion(apiKey=44, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=45, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=46, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=47, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=48, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=49, minVersion=0, maxVersion=1), ApiVersion(apiKey=50, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=51, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=56, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=57, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=60, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0), ApiVersion(apiKey=61, minVersion=0, maxVersion=0)], throttleTimeMs=0, supportedFeatures=[], finalizedFeaturesEpoch=0, finalizedFeatures=[], zkMigrationReady=false)
2023-06-27T11:44:52.985+05:30 DEBUG 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Node 0 has finalized features epoch: 0, finalized features: [], supported features: [], API versions: (Produce(0): 0 to 9 [usable: 9], Fetch(1): 0 to 12 [usable: 12], ListOffsets(2): 0 to 6 [usable: 6], Metadata(3): 0 to 11 [usable: 11], LeaderAndIsr(4): 0 to 5 [usable: 5], StopReplica(5): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], UpdateMetadata(6): 0 to 7 [usable: 7], ControlledShutdown(7): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], OffsetCommit(8): 0 to 8 [usable: 8], OffsetFetch(9): 0 to 7 [usable: 7], FindCoordinator(10): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], JoinGroup(11): 0 to 7 [usable: 7], Heartbeat(12): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], LeaveGroup(13): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], SyncGroup(14): 0 to 5 [usable: 5], DescribeGroups(15): 0 to 5 [usable: 5], ListGroups(16): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], SaslHandshake(17): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], ApiVersions(18): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], CreateTopics(19): 0 to 7 [usable: 7], DeleteTopics(20): 0 to 6 [usable: 6], DeleteRecords(21): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], InitProducerId(22): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], OffsetForLeaderEpoch(23): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], AddPartitionsToTxn(24): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], AddOffsetsToTxn(25): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], EndTxn(26): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], WriteTxnMarkers(27): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], TxnOffsetCommit(28): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], DescribeAcls(29): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], CreateAcls(30): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], DeleteAcls(31): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], DescribeConfigs(32): 0 to 4 [usable: 4], AlterConfigs(33): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], AlterReplicaLogDirs(34): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], DescribeLogDirs(35): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], SaslAuthenticate(36): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], CreatePartitions(37): 0 to 3 [usable: 3], CreateDelegationToken(38): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], RenewDelegationToken(39): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], ExpireDelegationToken(40): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], DescribeDelegationToken(41): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], DeleteGroups(42): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], ElectLeaders(43): 0 to 2 [usable: 2], IncrementalAlterConfigs(44): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], AlterPartitionReassignments(45): 0 [usable: 0], ListPartitionReassignments(46): 0 [usable: 0], OffsetDelete(47): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeClientQuotas(48): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], AlterClientQuotas(49): 0 to 1 [usable: 1], DescribeUserScramCredentials(50): 0 [usable: 0], AlterUserScramCredentials(51): 0 [usable: 0], AlterPartition(56): 0 [usable: 0], UpdateFeatures(57): 0 [usable: 0], Envelope(58): UNSUPPORTED, DescribeCluster(60): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeProducers(61): 0 [usable: 0], DescribeTransactions(65): UNSUPPORTED, ListTransactions(66): UNSUPPORTED, AllocateProducerIds(67): UNSUPPORTED).
2023-06-27T11:44:52.988+05:30 DEBUG 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] ProducerId of partition ispTopic-0 set to 2004 with epoch 0. Reinitialize sequence at beginning.
2023-06-27T11:44:52.988+05:30 DEBUG 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.RecordAccumulator    : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Assigned producerId 2004 and producerEpoch 0 to batch with base sequence 0 being sent to partition ispTopic-0
2023-06-27T11:44:53.000+05:30 DEBUG 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Sending PRODUCE request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=PRODUCE, apiVersion=9, clientId=producer-1, correlationId=4, headerVersion=2) and timeout 30000 to node 0: {acks=-1,timeout=30000,partitionSizes=[ispTopic-0=73]}
2023-06-27T11:44:53.006+05:30 DEBUG 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] Received PRODUCE response from node 0 for request with header RequestHeader(apiKey=PRODUCE, apiVersion=9, clientId=producer-1, correlationId=4, headerVersion=2): ProduceResponseData(responses=[TopicProduceResponse(name='ispTopic', partitionResponses=[PartitionProduceResponse(index=0, errorCode=0, baseOffset=33, logAppendTimeMs=-1, logStartOffset=0, recordErrors=[], errorMessage=null)])], throttleTimeMs=0)
2023-06-27T11:44:53.010+05:30 DEBUG 15744 --- [ad | producer-1] o.a.k.c.p.internals.TransactionManager   : [Producer clientId=producer-1] ProducerId: 2004; Set last ack'd sequence number for topic-partition ispTopic-0 to 0
```

Any help would be appreciated.

I have tried consuming the messages using batch script and it is working.

Comment: Producers do not send to the broker immediately. They add to an in memory buffer, which you'll need to flush if only sending one event. Also, you should show `kafka-consumer-groups --describe` output for group1, but your logs are also missing ConsumerConfig output so maybe the listener isn't running at all